# Error code when I try to type "Y" then the if code doesn't work and go straight to else and finish

Tags: c++

this is my code

```
cout<<"Do you have a discount?? (Y/N) :";
cin>>code;
cout<<endl;
if (code=="Y"){
    all_cost = cost - 100000;
}
else {
    all_cost = cost;
}
```

the rest of the code all works, only this if code doesn't work

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what doesn't work? compiler warnings? output?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code and added a `string code` declaration and it worked finde for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Do you have a discount?? (Y/N) :";
    string code;
    int all_cost = 0;
    int cost = 0;
    cin>>code;
    cout<<endl;
    if (code=="Y"){
        all_cost = cost - 100000;
    }else {
        all_cost = cost;
    }
    cout<<all_cost<<endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using char* to define code as I showed in the following example. Then the result will fail your purpose. Because, the char* is not an object. There exists not boolean comparison between two char*'s.

There are two ways to change your code besides Dawnb had suggested to use string (an object): 1. use char comparison instead of char* (shown as follows); 2. using the library function  *std::strcmp(code, "Y") == 0*   to compare two char*'s.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Do you have a discount?? (Y/N) :";
    char *code;
    int all_cost = 0;
    int cost = 0;
    cin>>code;
    cout<<endl;
    if (code[0] =='Y'){
        all_cost = cost - 100000;
    }else {
        all_cost = cost;
    }
    cout<<all_cost<<endl;

}
```